# Rolling Countif

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I have a very large Dataset ~ 100000 rows with 2 columns, I want to calculate a rolling count based on 2 criterias, basically how many times value in col 1 wrt col 2.

Dataset looks like this

I have written the following code

This is partial dataset, actual has 100000 rows, I want the answer in col c

[image]

```
  Sub test()
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Dim id, data_week, ans,  a As Variant
   Dim p As Double

   a = 100000
   Debug.Print Now()


   id = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & a).Value
   data_week = Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & a).Value
   ans = Sheet1.Range("c2:c" & a).Value

   For p = 1 To a

   ans(p, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & p + 1), id(p, 1), 
   Sheet1.Range("b2:b" & p + 1), data_week(p, 1))

   Next p
   Sheet1.Range("c2:c" & a).Value = ans
   Debug.Print Now()
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  End Sub
```

This is taking awfully long in VBA, wondering if there's a faster way to do it interms optimising the code, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try. This takes 3 seconds to run.

```
Sub test3()
    Dim vDB, ans()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim a As Long
    Dim i As Long, id, myDay
    Dim n As Integer

    Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    a = 100000
    Debug.Print Now()
    With Ws
        vDB = .Range("a2", .Range("b" & a))
        ReDim ans(1 To UBound(vDB, 1), 1 To 1)
        id = vDB(1, 1)
        myDay = vDB(1, 2)
        For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
            If vDB(i, 1) <> "" Then
                If id = vDB(i, 1) And myDay = vDB(i, 2) Then
                    n = n + 1
                    ans(i, 1) = n
                Else
                    id = vDB(i, 1)
                    myDay = vDB(i, 2)
                    n = 1
                    ans(i, 1) = n
                End If
            End If
            DoEvents
        Next
        .Range("c2").Resize(UBound(ans)) = ans
    End With

    Debug.Print Now()
End Sub
```